# Sweet Alert confirmation before delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

Hi I am new in using sweet alert js to make my alert box more fancy. I am using the normal javascript alert confirmation to delete a specific data in my table. However when I try to run a sweet alert confirmation before deleting it deletes the file without the confirmation popping up.

Here is the code in my JS below.

```
<script>
    archiveFunction() {
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, archive it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been archived.", "success");
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
    }
</script>
```

this is my html form below.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_id" id="p_id" value="<?php echo $rows['p_id']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="archive" onclick="archiveFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                Archive
        </button>
</form>
```

and here is the code in php.

```
<?php

include('../config.php');

if(isset($_POST['archive']))
{
$p_id = $_REQUEST['p_id'];
// sql to delete a record
$sqli = "UPDATE students SET archive = 2 WHERE p_id=$p_id";

if ($conn->query($sqli) === TRUE) {
    echo "swal('Archived!', 'Click ok to see!', 'success')";
} else {
    echo "Error Archiving record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close(); 
}
?>
```

what I want to happen is to confirm the sweet alert confirmation before deleting the specific data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other mentioned, your button click is submitting the form to the specified action and you are not able to chose your option in the alert. So you should prevent the form submit by using `event.preventDefault()` and submitting the form only when user press yes.

```js
function archiveFunction() {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
var form = event.target.form; // storing the form
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, archive it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    form.submit();          // submitting the form when user press yes
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<form action="abc" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_id" id="p_id" value="<?php echo $rows['p_id']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" name="archive" type="submit" onclick="archiveFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                Archive
        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried it. Btw is the abc action? If I click yes nothing happens.

Comment: abc is just a dummy action. Replace it with your action. In this example it is routing to abc, on pressing yes and we will get a 404 ,as abc is just a dummy url

Comment: I tried changing it but still won't submit it. Can we continue the discussion in the chatroom if you're available?

Comment: Sure we can have a discussion

Comment: Sorry I have slow connection maybe on thursday. Btw I am using a isset post in the same page where I created the form to archive. I did not use any action only php server as it self. How do I do that without doing the action in the form.

Comment: But your following HTML code `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` shows that you are using action.

Comment: Sorry about that I made it work when submitting it to other page where the sql and php code is placed. But how do I do it using the isset post method?

Comment: you forgot add event in ``onclick="archiveFunction(event)"`` please added to make complete answers

Answer (score 2):

This delete confirmation code with sweet alerts in express js

My code:

```js
function validateForm() {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
      var form = document.forms["myForm"]; // storing the form
      swal({
             title: "Are you sure?",
             text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
             icon: "warning",
             buttons: true,
             dangerMode: true,
           })
          .then((willDelete) => {
               if (willDelete) {
                     form.submit();
               } else {
                      swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
           }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<form name="myForm"  method="POST" action="/delete">
      <input type="hidden" value="<%= alldata[i]._id %>" name="std_id"> 
      <input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're not preventing the default behaviour of the browser by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return` with either `false` or `true` accordingly.

```
function [...](e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...]
}
```

Change,

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="archive" onclick="archiveFunction()">
```

to,

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="archive" onclick="archiveFunction(event)">
```

to pass the event argument for inline event listeners.

**Alternatively** if the `form` is not required then you can just remove the `form` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<form>` and replace:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
```

to:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger ajax_delete" type="button">
```

call onclick function from the "ajax_delete" through

```
$(".ajax_delete").on("click", function (){ /*your sweet alert code and after ajax call function */});
```

After that put your delete code to ajax call file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function archiveFunction() {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
var form = event.target.form; // storing the form
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, archive it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    form.submit();          // submitting the form when user press yes
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<form action="abc" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="p_id" id="p_id" value="<?php echo $rows['p_id']; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" name="archive" type="submit" onclick="archiveFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                Archive
        </button>
</form>
```